# Error My SQL in Java Language (Netbeans)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp, netbeans-8

I have code:

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    try {
        con = Connect.ConnectDB();
        if (PatientID.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please retrieve Patient ID", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        if (txtNoOfDays.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter no. of days", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        if (txtServiceCharges.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please retrieve service charges", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        if (txtBillingDate.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter billing date", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        if (txtTotalPaid.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter total paid", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        double add1 = Double.parseDouble(txtRoomCharges.getText());
        double add = Double.parseDouble(txtNoOfDays.getText());
        double add2 = add * add1;
        txtTotalRoomCharges.setText(String.valueOf(add2));
        double add3 = Double.parseDouble(txtServiceCharges.getText());
        double add5 = ((add * add1) + add3);
        txtTotalCharges.setText(String.valueOf(add5));
        double paid = Double.parseDouble(txtTotalPaid.getText());
        txtTotalPaid.setText(String.valueOf(paid));
        if (add5 > paid) {
            double datadue = add5 - paid;
            txtDueCharges.setText(String.valueOf(datadue));
        }
        //double add1 = Double.parseDouble(txtTotalCharges.getText());
        //double add2 = Double.parseDouble(txtTotalPaid.getText());

        Statement stmt;
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql1 = "Select DischargeID from bill_room where DischargeID= " + txtDischargeID.getText() + "";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
        if (rs.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record already exists", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        String sql = "insert into bill_room(DischargeID,BillingDate,RoomCharges,ServiceCharges,PaymentMode,PaymentModeDetails,ChargesPaid,DueCharges,TotalCharges,NoOfDays,TotalRoomCharges) values(" + txtDischargeID.getText() + ",'" + txtBillingDate.getText() + "'," + txtRoomCharges.getText() + "," + txtServiceCharges.getText() + ",'" + cmbPaymentMode.getSelectedItem() + "','" + txtPaymentModeDetails.getText() + "'," + txtTotalPaid.getText() + "," + txtDueCharges.getText() + "," + txtTotalCharges.getText() + "," + txtNoOfDays.getText() + "," + txtTotalRoomCharges.getText() + ")";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Successfully saved", "Record", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        btnSave.setEnabled(false);

    } catch (HeadlessException | SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);
    }
```

I have this code, when the execution runs (sometimes goes well, sometimes error.)
When error happen:
[image]

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jbdc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException" You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for right sysntax to use near
>   '110800.0,9,10800.0); at line 1

When Run clearly[image]

What is not quite right here?
I need your help or your suggest

Comment: Using `PreparedStatement`s won't only solve this error, but also defend you from sql-injection attacks

Comment: As the error message tells you, your SQL syntax is broken.  You're dynamically building SQL based on input at runtime (which, by the way, is wide open to SQL injection attacks), so we don't know what SQL code you're actually executing.  When you debug, what's the actual SQL code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use PreparedStatement why you don't use it properly, so to avoid syntax error and SQL injection you can use :

```
String sql = "insert into bill_room(DischargeID, BillingDate, "
        + "RoomCharges, ServiceCharges, PaymentMode, PaymentModeDetails, "
        + "ChargesPaid, DueCharges, TotalCharges, NoOfDays, TotalRoomCharges) "
        + "values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,  ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {

    insert.setInt(1, txtDischargeID.getText());
    insert.setString(2, txtBillingDate.getText());

    //...Set the the right type if int use setInt if string use setString ...

    insert.setDouble(11, Double.parseDouble(txtTotalRoomCharges.getText()));

    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

same thing with select.